# find duplicate records in the table with all columns are the same

Tags: sql, group-by

Say If I have a table with hundreds of columns. The task is that I want to find out duplicate records with all the columns are the same, basically find out identical records.

I tried group by as the following

```
select *
from some_table
group by *
having count(*) > 1
```

but it seems like `group by *` is not allowed in sql. Anyone has some idea as to what kind of command I could run to find out identical records? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent tags. Please tag with the specific database.

Comment: I'm using mysql but it does not work for sql server as well. It's an sql interview question I saw online and it does not mention any constraint or pk.

Answer (score 0):

Just put comma separated list of columns instead of `*` in both places - `select` and `group by`.  Buy not `count` - the `count(*)` should remain as is.

I verified it on SQL Server, but I am pretty sure it is ANSI SQL and should work on most (any?) ANSI SQL compatible RDBMS.

Comment: suppose there are hundreds of columns, is doing this feasible?

Comment: If you do not have primary key - the only way is to compare all columns.  I cannot see why not.  If there is at least one good index (index with good selectivity) - make sure you group by columns of that index first - that would make it much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql solution, I think.

SELECT all rows, and use EXCEPT ALL to remove one of each (the SELECT DISTINCT). Now we will have the duplicates only.

```
select * from table
except all
select distinct * from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to list out all the columns:

```
select col1, col2, col3, . . .
from t
group by col1, col2, col3, . . .
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL 2016+

Add a new column in the table to hash all the columns, [MSSQL HashBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

notes to consider:

1. you need to convert all the columns to Varchar or Varbinary.
2. is you comparison case sensitive, if yes use upper() or lower()
3. Null values, use column sperator.
4. the hashing algorithm Performance on the server.

for me usualy go for something like

```
select col1 , col2, col3 , col4 
,HASHBYTES ( 'MD5',
concat( 
      Convert (varbinary ,col1),'|'
     ,Convert (varbinary ,col2),'|'
     ,Convert (varbinary ,col3),'|'
     ,Convert (varbinary ,col4),'|'
     )
          ) as Row_Hash
  from table1
```

the the row_hash can be use as a singl column in the table/CTE to present the content of all the other columns

you can count by it and Order by it to find the duplicates